# How can we create an image from an entire disk?

Tags: backup, clone, dd, disk-image

I've tried clonezilla live cd, and I got an image but in a kind of folder. I would need an .img file or something because afterwards I will use some images together, but that is other story.

I also used `dd if=/dev/sda of=~/disk1.img` but it doesn't finish the image because the disk has 500GB and the image just about 100MB the first time and 2GB the second time, so I think that stops before finish for any reason I'm not aware of.

Do you know any way of doing an image of a disk?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favourite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I don't think that I'm asking that. I just want to create an image and I don't know how to do it. Should I change the way of asking this question?

Comment: "_free software if it is possible_" This is you asking that.

Comment: If the problem was that, it is already resolved!

Comment: This question is off-topic for [so] because it's not about programming. You could try asking on [su], but be aware that product recommendations are off-topic on every StackExchange site.

Comment: Yes, guys, it is not about programming, but is it worth not to help therefor? Joe, dd is already free software :-) Is the partition where you want to save the copy different from sda? What about ddrescue ? You could mount a third partition or drive and use ddrescue if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb/disk1.img /dev/sdc/errorlog.txt

Comment: 1) *dd* is the correct command for this kind of jobs. But: 2) you are trying to image /dev/sda, are you sure it is not in use as you image it? 3) A disk of 500GB will produce an image of 500GB. Do you have a disk large enough to contain the image?

Comment: Yes, I bought a disk of 4TB for that purpose. Could I recover the copy in the point it stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command and options to avoid the process to stop when it find some bad sectors

```
dd conv=noerror,sync if=<whatever> of=<whatever>
```

---

**dd** OPTION

*conv=CONVS*
 convert the file as per the comma separated symbol list

Each CONV symbol may be:

**noerror** continue after read errors

**sync** pad every input block with NULs to ibs-size; when used with block or unblock, pad with spaces rather than NULs

---

More info [Man dd command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)

Comment: What is this? it is a part of a command, or part of dd?

Comment: @Joe yes dd conv=noerror,sync if=<whatever>  of=<whatever>